# Running Total in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using MS Access database, and I want to generate Daily Stock Report From the Table Tmp4 as follows,

Dt__________OpStk___PQty___SQty

01/04/2014___120_____0_______4

04/04/2014_____0_____0_______2

08/04/2014_____0_____0_______1

11/04/2014_____0____20_______3

16/04/2014_____0_____0_______5

25/04/2014_____0____10_______3

NOTE: - Closing Stock = Opening Stock + Purchase Qty - Sales Qty

I have used following query

```
'SELECT A1.DT, A1.OpStk, A1.PQty, A1.SQty,
(SELECT SUM(A2.OpStk+A2.PQty-SQty) FROM Tmp4 AS A2
WHERE A2.DT <=A1.DT) AS ClosingStk
FROM Tmp4 AS A1'
```

Which gives me following result

Dt__________OpStk___PQty___SQty____ClosingStk

01/04/2014___120_____0_______4_______116

04/04/2014_____0_____0_______2_______114

08/04/2014_____0_____0_______1_______113

11/04/2014_____0____20_______3_______130

16/04/2014_____0_____0_______5_______125

25/04/2014_____0____10_______3_______132

The Daily Stock Report which I want is as follows,

Dt__________OpStk___PQty___SQty____ClosingStk

01/04/2014___120_____0_______4_______116

04/04/2014___116_____0_______2_______114

08/04/2014___114_____0_______1_______113

11/04/2014___113____20_______3_______130

16/04/2014___130_____0_______5_______125

25/04/2014___125____10_______3_______132

Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think you can just substitute the A1.OpStk on the first line for the longer version, which adds up to the previouly closed stock price:

```
SELECT A1.DT, (SELECT SUM(A2.OpStk+A2.PQty-SQty) FROM Tmp4 AS A2 WHERE A2.DT <=A1.DT) AS OpStk, A1.PQty, A1.SQty,
(SELECT SUM(A2.OpStk+A2.PQty-SQty) FROM Tmp4 AS A2
WHERE A2.DT <=A1.DT) AS ClosingStk
FROM Tmp4 AS A1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. The query you've given gives slightly different result. So I modified it as

```
SELECT A1.DT, (SELECT SUM(A2.OpStk+A2.PQty-A2.SQty) FROM Tmp4 AS A2 WHERE A2.DT < A1.DT) AS OpStk,
A1.PQty, A1.SQty,
(SELECT SUM(A2.OpStk+A2.PQty-A2.SQty) FROM Tmp4 AS A2
WHERE A2.DT <=A1.DT) AS ClosingStk
FROM Tmp4 AS A1;
```

And that solved it. Thanks a ton for showing me the way.